# Why does java not convert my time correctly?

Tags: java

I have the following method to convert a String to Date object

```
public Date convertTime(String time) {

    SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/y HH:mm:ss.S");
    try {
        return parser.parse(time);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }


}
```

I have the following method to convert it back

```
public String dateToTimeMillis(Date date) {

    //StringBuffer formatted = new StringBuffer();
    SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.S");
    try {
        String formatted = parser.format(date);
        return formatted;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }


}
```

The following test code

```
    TraderLib lib = new TraderLib();
    Date d1 = lib.convertTime("01/11/2011 10:41:09.045");
    System.out.println(lib.dateToTimeMillis(d1));
```

returns 10:41:09.45

How do I preserve the 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set the format to:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/y HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

to preserve 3 digits. From the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#number):

"Number: For formatting, the number of pattern letters is the minimum number of digits, and shorter numbers are zero-padded to this amount. For parsing, the number of pattern letters is ignored unless it's needed to separate two adjacent fields."

Comment: @deltanovember, any plans to accept an answer for this question? Did this answer work for you?

Answer (score 3):

Use `SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/y HH:mm:ss.SSS");`